# Can't log into Centos SSH server after changing port

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, login

I was changing my ssh server's port to create a honeypot.

I changed the port through /etc/ssh/sshd_config

It originally said

```
#Port 22
```

And I changed to

```
Port 69
```

I now realise that I can't log back into it.
I am hosting the server through AWS ec2.

Please can somebody tell me how I can re-login to the server as there is years worth of shit on it!

Answer (score 2):

The number itself doesn't mean you're using UDP. Most probably, sshd is running on TCP with port 69. In this case, try to allow incoming traffic to TCP 69 by modifying a security group attached to this instance.

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: You can search for something like "AWS how to open a port in a security group".

Comment: Log in on the console and tinker with it (or put it back to 22)

Comment: @BrandonXavier how would I do that exactly?

Comment: @Tim I have added a Custom TCP rule with the port that I want but I don't know how to connect to it.

Comment: here's one easy way: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html#ec2-instance-connect-connecting-console

Comment: Good idea, Systems Manager Session Manager uses a different mechanism. Log in like that and fix SSH. @1423 you have to make sure you've allowed access on a port that you've already configured SSH for. If that's not working you may have to restore from snapshot / backup, or create a new instance and mount the existing drive as a data drive to copy your data over.

Comment: @BrandonXavier It says "There was a problem connecting to your instance" and "We were unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance’s network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. For more information, see Task 1: Configure network access to an instance."